# Jmeter- Not ALL samples show up in Aggregate Report-

Tags: jmeter

I have a test where I have 120 samples.  However, the report shows 115 samples at the third step and test is still running. I do not see any errors.  Do I take this as failed opening the 3rd page or since there is no error,can I assume, my app is able to take 120 samples?[image]

Comment: Maybe it has sth to do with the tick beside the 'Log/Display Only Successes'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set 'Successes' for Log/Display only, JMeter will not show the failed requests. Error % will be 0 always as you hide all the failed requests. So do not assume that you have no errors.

Retest by unchececking 'Successes' checkbox and confirm the behavior yourself. If you still face issue, update the question with more information.

Answer (score 1):

```
If you select the
```

> Success check box

[image]

`It will only display the passed sampler that why you are not able to see the failed sampler.
Deselect that then you will able to see all the sampler`